# What's the correct way to install plugins on templating system?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-blade

Imagine I have some different pages 3-4 pages.
Imagine also that I'm using multiple js plugins, that they normally need a
css styling on head tag, script tag at the end of the body, some for inclusion some for init.
And also they need a HTML snippet in the body for positioning.

Having a templating system behind, such as Blade, what would be the correct way in order to optimize plugin inclusion (i.e. some plugin included in some pages?)

Some ideas:
- include dependencies everywhere (on the parent template)
- work on names sections (HEAD, BODY, after /BODY TAG) and yeld plugins as needed..

Is there some better approach? What would be the correct most elegant way?